# Add hosted content while sending chat message in Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How to add hosted content, such as inline images or videos when sending a message in Teams channel via UI? I know there is limited support for this via API, however I am interested in the UI upload.

Have tried uploading images/videos several times, but these always get converted to attachment objects, and not hosted content.

Comment: You can upload a file to Sharepoint and then share the link or add them like file attachments.

Comment: You can send it as an OG link within the content. OR You can use aws s3 links as well.